# How to use jQuery to horizontally scroll all the way to the right on a narrow pop-up window

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a solution to first open a jQuery browser window with a separate html file at the far right of the screen but within that narrow new window, I need to scroll all the way to the far right.

What I have working so far with the script below is the opening of a separate html file (which will be the same site as what I am on, but I want to present just a narrow section of it) at the far right of the screen and with the width of 350px. What I am looking to accomplish is horizontally scrolling the contents of the new windw all the way to the right. I can find solutions for horizontal scrolling in the parent window but not the pop-up child window.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.jsNewWindow').click(function() {
    // opens in new window to the far right, accounting for multiple monitors
    window.open(this.href, "customWindow", "width=350, height=900, top=0, left=9000");
    return false;
  });
});
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <a href="box.html" class="jsNewWindow">click me</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Is the `href` in the same domain as the original window? If not, the main script can't do anything in the new window.

Comment: Thanks. I have clarified the title and provided more detail on the question for exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me. Keep in mind that if you are testing this out, you need to have a separate html page (box.html in my case) that has a width wide enough to horizontally scroll. I used a style to set it to a width of 1000px and height of 100px.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Open New Window at Far Right and Scroll Full Right.</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.jsNewWindow').click(function() {
    // opens in new window to the far right, accounting for multiple monitors
      var customWindow = window.open(this.href, "customWindow", "width=350, height=900, top=0, left=9000");
      $(function() {
        // waits for dom to load and then scrolls all the way to the right.
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(customWindow.document).scrollLeft(2000);
        }, 50);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <a href="box.html" class="jsNewWindow">click me</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the instance of the child dom in a jQuery element and then call `.scrollleft()` on it giving scrollleft an int of the pixels to scroll by (possibly 9000 given the left attribute you defined in your question)

Something like:

```
var popup = window.open(this.href, "customWindow", "width=350, height=900, top=0, left=9000");

$(popup.document).ready(function () {
  $(popup.document).scrollleft(9000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Keith! This set me on the right track but so much of what I tried failed until I learned that a delay needs to be set. The dom has to load just for a moment first before an action like scrolling can be applied.